# How can I highlight a word in a Vuetify card when using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to highlight a certain word in the text of a *Vuetify* card but when I include the tag it includes it literally without interpreting it as an HTML tag.

I've tried using

```
str.replace('word', '<mark>word</mark>')
```

```
//template
<v-card>
    <v-card-text>{{ markedPassage }}</v-card-text>
</v-card>

// script
data() {
    return {
      markedPassage: "some text <mark>word</mark>"
    }
  }
```

https://codepen.io/edlgg/pen/KKPmojm

I want the selected word to be highlighted. I would also like to be able to change the color but that should be easy to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `v-html` directive as follows :

```
  <v-card-text v-html="markedPassage"></v-card-text>
```

check this [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/pozPVvr?editors=1010)